# Need help creating a method for ksmallest using a comparator?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have to create a method called ksmallest using a comparator. I followed the instructions my professor gave me but I am not exactly sure if I created the method correctly. Here are his instructions:

1. Define a new comparator, , that reverses the ordering imposed by the comparator  which is given as a parameter.
2. Construct a max priority queue using the comparator .
3. Iterate through the input list . For each element  of , if the current size of the priority queue is less than , then add  to the priority queue. Otherwise, compare  with the current maximum element in the priority queue. Do nothing if  is larger or equal. If  is smaller, remove the maximum element and add  to the priority queue.
4. At this point the priority queue contains exactly the  smallest elements of . Until the priority queue is empty, remove each element and add it to a list in the correct order. You can decide what type of Java list to use.

   ```
   '
   public static <T> List<T> kSmallestFaster(List<T> A, int k, Comparator<T> compare) {
            if (k > A.size()) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("k too large");
            }

            Comparator<T> revComp = compare.reversed();
            PriorityQueue<T> maxPq = new PriorityQueue<T>(k,revComp);
            List<T> res = new ArrayList<>();

            for(T a: A) {
            if(maxPq.size() < k) {
                   maxPq.add(a);
                }
                else if(compare.compare(a, maxPq.peek()) < 0)  {
                     res.add(maxPq.remove());
                     maxPq.add(a); 
                }
             }
             return res;
        }
   '
   ```

Comment: What's the actual problem you want help with? Rather than hope people will wade through your questions and your code hoping they'll find something, if you can provide some details (such as your actual output vs your expected output), you're much more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: The way to determine if you created the method correctly is to *test* it. Feed it some sample data, feed it to your method, and examine the result. Did you get the results you expected? If not, debug and repeat. If so, test with different data. Examine your code for edge conditions and create test cases for them.

Comment: By the way, what you currently have is not correct, which you will discover if you test it. And the error will become quite evident once you look at the results.